# how can i output IRC server details via php on my website?

Tags: php, irc, usage-statistics, visitor-statistic

i want to tell people details of how many users are in my server.. and possibly a specific channel, if that is possible. my website's in PHP.

litterally a network "statistics" sctipt for my IRC network. doesn't have to be real time, but it should gather the data when the page is loaded such as php normally does.

Comment: Sorry, this is by far to broad a question for a place answering _specific programming questions_. Please do your own research, start coding yourself, and then, if you have an issue with your specific code, _then_ is the time to ask here. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.magirc.org/ is a front end for anope "StatServ" which is a channel statistics IRC service. basically, it takes the data collected from StatServ on your IRC network and makes graphs and shows information. it supports MySQL and anope.